# AWS API Gateway return binary file from base64 browser error

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a AWS lambda in python 2.7 which receives an id,
retrieves the file from a s3 bucket and turns it into base64:

```
response = s3.Object( s3_bucket, r['prefix'] + str( id) ).get()
data = base64.b64encode( response['Body'].read())
return data
```

Everything is right, the base64 generated is tested and correct. It is a jpeg.

Now on api gateway:

- create API
- add to Binary support binary media type: image/jpeg
- add GET method to resources.
- add  Method Response HTTP Status: 200 Models: image/jpeg => Empty
- add Content-Type:= image/jpeg in "Intergration Response" status 200 > "Body Mapping Templates"

With this Templates:

```
$util.base64Decode($input.body)
```

Deploy API, test... and 
Browser said: the image can not be displayed because it contains errors.

I tried a hundred different versions without result. What is my mistake?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to return an image as base64, but assuming you have your reasons, don't you need to add something like a `Content-Encoding: base64` response header so that the browser understands what it is dealing with?

Comment: lambda function return a Base64 image. I want api gateway returns a binary. For this I use `$util.base64Decode($input.body)`, but does not work well.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that, at present, you can not solve this problem through the web console. As suggested by daveg you must use the AWS CLI to change to setting contentHandling = CONVERT_TO_TEXT. Operation that, as I said, you can not do on the web interface.

For more information: [aws forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=768110)